# PATCH django tastypie: Different data type in validation

Tags: tastypie

I have a ModelResource with a datetime field called 'start_time'.

When i make a PATCH req with this field included in my request json, i can use this value as a string inside the custom clean_start_time validation in an attached Django Form.

However, when this field is missing from the PATCH request, the type of the field is now datetime.datetime
I guess tastypie populates missing fields from existing values, but now they are no longer strings.

Am I doing something wrong? Should i configure this field somehow inside the ModelForm? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your field has a default value. As far as I understand [tastypie populates defaults](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1823) from your the model a ModelResource points to. If you do not want that kind of behaviour you can declare the field explicitly with

`attr_name = fields.DateTimeField(attribute='attr_name', blank=True, default=fields.NOT_PROVIDED)`